# how to call a function on button click

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I want to create two buttons that perform separate functions.

[image]

When `button_B1` is clicked, `Function_B1()` runs.

When `button_B2` is clicked, `Function_B2()` runs.

How do I call a function on a button click?

Comment: Please provide the code you already have.

Comment: `WM_COMMAND` messages are generated when a button is clicked. I suggest you read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Win32 button is clicked, it sends a [`BN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/bn-clicked) notification to its parent window, where the message carries the button's HWND and ID.  In the parent window's wndproc, you can catch the notification and call whatever function you want for whichever button is sending the notification.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    if ((HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) && (lParam != 0))
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case ID_BTN1:
                Function_B1();
                break;

            case ID_BTN2:
                Function_B2();
                break;
        }
    }

    break:
}
```

Or

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    if ((HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) && (lParam != 0))
    {
        HWND hwndBtn = (HWND) lParam;

        if (hwndBtn == hwndBtn1)
            Function_B1();

        else if (hwndBtn == hwndBtn2)
            Function_B2();
    }

    break:
}
```

Comment: You should check ID or HWND first. If you put some custom control that notifies with value 0 (BN_CLICKED is defined as 0), you can end in wrong branch. Menu also uses 0.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Remy.
I just had a problem with the switch statement:

```
    case WM_COMMAND:
     {  
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case 1:
            Function_B1(hWnd, wParam, lParam);
            break;

        case 2:
            Function_B2(hWnd, wParam, lParam);

            break;

        case 3:
            Function_B3(hWnd, wParam, lParam);
            break;
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. `int wmId = LOWORD(wParam)`?